# raise exc.NoSuchModuleError( sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgresql

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I created a sample flask application, I want to connect PostgreSQL database to my project.
I installed flask_sqlalchemy.

here is my Code

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://michealscott:dwight@localhost:5432/michealscott'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email  = email



@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

I cd-ed into my src directory and executed:

```
python
>> from app import db
>> db.create_all()
```

then the above error shows up.

After searching over internet. I also did

```
pip install psycopg2
```

still no luck.

there is a same question on stack overflow and couple of answers/suggestions. I was not able to comment on the post so asking it again pardon me!

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the result of `python -c 'import sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql'` and `pip freeze`?

Comment: Output for pip freeze. 

`click==7.1.2. 
Flask==1.1.2. 
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4. 
itsdangerous==1.1.0. 
Jinja2==2.11.3. 
MarkupSafe==1.1.1. 
psycopg2==2.8.6. 
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6. 
SQLAlchemy==1.3.23. 
Werkzeug==1.0.1`. 

output for python -c `import sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql`.  
  
`Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>. 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql' `.

Comment: That's strange. Can you do everything all over again in a brand new virtualenv? Please take note of any possible warning/failures when installing psycopg.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I uninstalled Flask, SQLAlchemy, Flask_SQLAlchemy and did everything from scratch. 
Please go ahead and answer so that I can mark it as an actual answer to this question.